# Android device can't ping PC through adb shell

Tags: android, networking, adb, client-server, ping

I have my Android phone connected to my PC (Windows 10 with Android SDK installed). I set up my PC to have a mobile hotspot so the phone can be connected to the PC network. My PC can ping the phone's IP address, but when I want to ping the PC from the phone's shell (through `adb shell`), it just can't ping it. I have a HTTP server on the PC and need the phone to reach to the server, which is not reachable right now.

The PC IP address is `192.168.137.1`:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::345d:2505:82fa:3cd5%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

And the phone's IP address is `192.168.137.159`:

```
wlan0     Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet addr:192.168.137.159  Bcast:192.168.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5ca7:98ff:feea:cb17/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16441523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8750144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:17116348103 TX bytes:4458547550
```

I also tried it without mobile hotspot when both connect to the same router, but same issue again.

**What is the problem?** Does Windows have some settings that need to be changed for visibility and reachability?

Comment: Check your PC's firewall settings.

Comment: Idk what exactly to check.

Comment: I'd bet google knows.

Answer (score 0):

You are already connected via `adb` (as you mentioned `adb shell`), then just do a reverse port mapping (*changes ports according to your case*)

```
adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

then, when your device access `localhost:8080` it will be redirected to `yourpc:8080`.